# Prove $\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{q^n+q^{-n}}=\tfrac14(\vartheta_3^2(q)-1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, analytic-number-theory, theta-functions

> Prove that $$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{q^n+q^{-n}}=\tfrac14(\vartheta_3^2(q)-1),$$
>   provided by [Wolfam](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F%28x%5En+%2B+x%5E%28-n%29%29+from+n%3D1+to+n%3Dinf).

Note that here, we use the notational conventions $$\vartheta_3(z,q)=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}q^{n^2}e^{2niz},$$
$$\vartheta_3(q)\equiv \vartheta_3(0,q),$$
and of course $\vartheta_3^2(q)=\vartheta_3(q)\cdot\vartheta_3(q)$.

---

I have gotten a significant portion of the way. We have that 
$$f(q)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{q^n+q^{-n}}=L(q,-1;q^2),$$
where $$L(a,b;q)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{a^n}{1-bq^n}\qquad |q|>1.$$
It can be shown, for sufficient $a$ and $b$, that $$L(a,b;q)=L(b^{-1},a^{-1};q).$$
This is the case here, so we have $$f(q)=L(-1,q^{-1};q^2),$$
which is $$f(q)=L(1,q^{-2};q^4)-L(1,q^{-3};q^4),$$
by splitting the sum up into parts of even and odd index. This may be evaluated in terms of the $q$-digamma function $\psi_q(s)$ as 
$$f(q)=\tfrac1{4\ln q}\left(\psi_{q^{-4}}(\tfrac34)-\psi_{q^{-4}}(\tfrac14)\right).$$
This is $$4f(q)\ln q=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\ln\left[\Gamma_{q^{-4}}(\tfrac12+s)\Gamma_{q^{-4}}(\tfrac12-s)\right]\bigg|_{s=1/4}.$$
Then from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Relation_to_the_q-gamma_function) we can show that 
$$\left(\Gamma_{q^{-4}}(\tfrac12+s)\Gamma_{q^{-4}}(\tfrac12-s)\right)^{-1}=\frac{q^{4s^2+3}}{(q^4;q^4)_\infty^3 (1-q^4)}\vartheta_4(-2is\ln q, q^2),$$
but I have no idea about how the logarithmic derivative (w.r.t $s$) of this has anything to do with $\vartheta_3^2$. Could I have some help? Thanks.

Comment: See [this](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/02/elliptic-functions-theta-functions-contd.html) too.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/737894/72031).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much.

Comment: @clathratus: often there is lot of valuable material here which is unfortunately difficult to search. The linked answer was in my favorite list and yet it took me quite some time to search.

Comment: Also the theory of elliptic and theta functions is somewhat difficult but not as difficult as it is projected to be. I found the treatments by Ramanujan and Jacobi to be much simpler.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to prove it, the sum of squares theorem.

- Show that $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID where $(p)$ is a prime ideal iff $p\equiv 3\bmod 4$, thus $\frac14 \sum_{a,b}(a^2+b^2)^{-s}=\zeta(s)L(s,\chi_4)$
- Show that both $(\sum_n e^{2i\pi n^2 z})^2$ and $1+4\sum_n (\sum_{d| n}\chi_4(d)) e^{2i\pi nz}\in M_1(\Gamma_1(4))$ and that the latter space of modular forms is finite dimensional thus it suffices to compare finitely many coefficients to prove they are equal

Comment: Ah I see there is a lot more theory here than I had expected. I have not taken any number theory courses though. I was hoping for a proof based on manipulations and functional identities, is such a proof possible?