# Proving $\left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x^{n^{2}}\right)^{2}=1+4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{x^{-\left(2n+1\right)}-1}$

Tags: summation

$$\left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x^{n^{2}}\right)^{2}=1+4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{x^{-\left(2n+1\right)}-1}$$
Proving:
$$\left(1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n^{2}}\right)^{2}=1+4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{1-x^{2n+1}}$$

This is reduced to the form:
$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n^{2}}\right)^{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n^{2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{1-x^{2n+1}}$$
The Sum on Right can be rewritten to the form:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{1+x^{2n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{n}+x^{-n}}$$
or,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}x^{j^{2}+i^{2}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n^{2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{n}+x^{-n}}$$

I am unable to manipulate it any further to prove the equality.

This is taken from the Answer made [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1799044) by User Sangchul Lee and someone made a post to ask the same question but the post seems to have been deleted and no proof is present for this so I am asking it here again.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734615)

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for the comment, that is quite a complicated proof.

Comment: Another proof is based on Fourier series for elliptic function $\operatorname{dn} (u, k) $ namely $$\operatorname{dn} (u, k) =\frac{\pi} {2K}+\frac{2\pi} {K} \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{q^n\cos(n\pi u/K)} {1+q^{2n}}$$ The identity in question is arrived at by putting $u=0$.